# Need to extract substrings based on key words

Tags: ruby, regex, string, parsing

I have a string (a block of cdata from a soap) that looks roughly like:

```
     "<![CDATA[XXX|^~\&
      KEY|^~\&|xxxxx|xxxxx^xxxx xxxxx 
      INFO||xxx|xxxxxx||xxxxx|xxxxxxx|xxxxxxx 
      INFO|||xxxxx||||xxxxxxxxx||||||||||xxxxxxxx              
      KEY|^~\&|xxxxxx|xxxxxxxxxx|xxxxxxxx    
      INFO||xx|xxxxxxxx||xxxxxxx|xxxxxx 
      INFO|||xxxx|x|||xxxxxxxxx|||||||x|||xxxxx|||xxxx||||||||||||||||||||||||xxxx
      KEY|^~\&|xxxxx|xxxxx^xxxx xxxxx 
      INFO||xxx|xxxxxx||xxxxx|xxxxxxx|xxxxxxx 
      INFO|||xxxxx||||xxxxxxxxx||||||||||xxxxxxxx  ]]>"
```

I am trying to figure how to safely parse out a string for each 'KEY' section using ruby. Basically I need a sting that looks like:

```
  "KEY|^~\&|xxxxx|xxxxx^xxxx xxxxx 
  INFO||xxx|xxxxxx||xxxxx|xxxxxxx|xxxxxxx 
  INFO|||xxxxx||||xxxxxxxxx||||||||||xxxxxxxx"
```

For each time there is a 'KEY'. Thoughts on the best way to go about this? Thanks.

Comment: I don't know anything about soap, so I apologize if this is irrelevant, but I would suggest using a [soap library](https://www.google.com/search?q=ruby+soap)

Comment: Yea I guess the soap part is irrelevant, I just mentioned in case someone may have seen this type of response before. Its really a ruby question. Just a string at this point. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: I trust you don't object to the edit I just did. Normally, I'd suggest changes in a comment, but I didn't know when you'd be back and was concerned that readers unfamilar with "cdata" would skip your question. (I was about to.) As you see, I removed the references to "cdata" and "XML" in the title and deleted the keywords "soap" and "cdata".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to do it (with a simplified example):

```
str = 
"<![CDATA[XXX|^~\&
KEY|^~\&|x
INFO||x
INFO|||x
KEY|^~\&|x
INFO||xx|x
INFO|||x
KEY|^~\&|x
INFO||x
INFO|||x"

r = /
    ^KEY\b         # match KEY at beginning of line followed by word boundary
    .+?            # match any number of any character, lazily
    (?=\bKEY\b|\z) # match KEY bracketed by word boundaries or end of
                   # string, in positive lookahead
    /mx            # multiline and extended modes

str.scan r
  #=> ["KEY|^~&|x\nINFO||x\nINFO|||x\n",
  #    "KEY|^~&|x\nINFO||xx|x\nINFO|||x\n",
  #    "KEY|^~&|x\nINFO||x\nINFO|||x"]
```

Comment: You may want to delete your comment, as it applied to an initial answer that I subsequently changed, so could be confusing.

Comment: Accepting this answer as it answers my original question and works perfectly. Sorry I am new to Stack Overflow, thank you for editing. However if I may ask one more thing: This works only when the 'KEY' is on a new line. What I am receiving is a jumbled mess and I terrible with regex to begin with. Is there an edit that can be made to the above code that would grab the 'KEY' section no matter where it lies?

Comment: If `"KEY"` is not necessarily at the beginning of a line, just replace `^` with `\b` (word break). That assumes the substring ends right before the next `\bKEY\b` (or the end of the string). Is that correct? Notice that `"INFO"` does not appear in my regex. Is that OK?

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much. Would upvote if I could.

Answer (score 0):

Not as relaxed of a regex as like, but this might work for you:

```
KEY(.+\n)+(?=\s+KEY)
```